# Segmentation fault when using php curl with client ceritifcate

Tags: php, curl, ssl, client

I'm doing a php application that is supposed to connect to a RESTful webservice, which requires a client certificate.

But I get a segmentation fault when using php curl with client ceritifcate.

Key and Certificate files are correct. I use php 5.3.3 on rhel 6.

Any help guys?

```
<?php

$url = 'https://10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


$data = array(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);    

echo($data_string);  
error_reporting(E_ALL);                                                                             

$ch = curl_init($url); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',  
    'Accept: application/json',          
    'User-Agent: Apache CXF 2.6.1', 
    'Cache-Control: no-cache', 
    'Pragma: no-cache',    
    'Connection: keep-alive',                                                                 
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, '/fullpath/b.key'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/fullpath/c.crt'); 




$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo(htmlentities($result));


?>
```

Comment: Update your curl lib :) (and PHP but if I remember correctly, it's CURL issue, not PHP)

Comment: It's up-to as per yum. I have version 7.19.7-26